How to prove the maximum principle about the first eigenvalue?
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded domain. Let $u\in C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ satisfy
$$-\Delta u+c(x)u\leqslant 0\ \ \text{in}\ \ \Omega.$$
We can assume $c(x)$ is sufficiently smooth if necessary. And the first eigenvalue of the operator $-\Delta +c(x)$ in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ is $\lambda_{1}>0$. Can I get
$$\sup_{\Omega}(u)\leqslant\sup_{\partial\Omega}(u^{+})?$$
I'm not sure this maximum principle is right, how to prove it?(or give a counterexample)

You've not imposed any assumptions in relation to $c$ and $\lambda_1$, so, as it is written, you are simply asking if the maximum principle for $-\Delta +c$ holds, which it does not in general

It does hold, however, if you assume $c>-\lambda^{\Delta}_1$ where $\lambda^{\Delta}_1$ is the first (Dirichlet) eigenvalue of $-\Delta$. Are you sure you didn't mean to take $\lambda_1 = \lambda^{\Delta}_1$ instead of the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta +c$?

Yes, $\lambda_{1}$ is the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $-\Delta+c(x)$ (not $-\Delta$). And there is no clear relationship between $c(x)$ and $\lambda_{1}$. I only know if $u\leqslant 0$ on $\partial\Omega$, then $u\leqslant 0$ in $\Omega$. But I don't know the case of $\sup_{\partial\Omega}(u^{+})>0$.

If this conclusion is wrong, are there any counterexamples?

Yes, if $u$ is the first Dirichlet eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ and $c=-\lambda_1^{\Delta}$ then $-\Delta u-\lambda_1^{\Delta}u=0\leq 0$, $u$ can be chosen to be positive in $\Omega$ and is zero on the boundary

But the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of the operator $-\Delta -\lambda_{1}^{\Delta}$ is $0$.
